# how to diagnose the originator of the signal 15 send to sshd

Tags: sshd, signals, trace

I recently met a issue that my sshd keep dead repeatly, I did the following check.

1. from the `/var/log/message`, I could see the sshd keeped restarting

   ```
   Apr 23 12:05:39 host1  systemd: Stopping OpenSSH server daemon...
   Apr 23 12:05:39 host1  systemd: Stopped OpenSSH server daemon.
   Apr 23 12:05:39 host1  systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
   Apr 23 12:05:39 host1  systemd: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
   ```
2. from the `/var/log/secure`, I found that sometimes singal 15 was received by sshd

   ```
   Apr 23 11:32:52 host1  sshd[105049]: Received signal 15; terminating.
   Apr 23 11:32:52 host1  sshd[111278]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 36000.
   Apr 23 11:32:52 host1  sshd[111278]: Received signal 15; terminating.
   Apr 23 11:32:52 host1  sshd[111306]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 36000.
   ```
3. I checked `sshd -t`, there is no syntax errors
4. In order to check who is sending signal 15 to the sshd, I tried the following, how should I tried the next time?

   ```
   [root@host1 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/signal/signal_deliver]# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/signal/enable
   [root@host1 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/signal/signal_deliver]# echo "sig == 15" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/signal/filter
   ```

Comment: That `systemd: Stopping OpenSSH server daemon...` should make it quite obvious what's sending SIGTERM to sshd, that's systemd when asked to stop the ssh service. Maybe the question you should ask is what requested the service to be stopped.

Comment: yes，you are correct

Answer (score 0):

There's no general Unix way to do that. Signals themselves don't carry that information. It depends on the actual operating system. So, as you already realized, you need to use kernel tracing to figure that one out on Linux.

The tracepoint you decided was probably not optimal – you're observing where signals get delivered, not where they originate! So, instead of `signal_deliver`, you would want to trace the entry of the `kill` syscall (because that's where we know who sends the signal), and its exit (because there we know whether it's actually been delivered).

While that *does* sound complicated, there's a tool that already does that:
The `bpftrace` utility comes with a lot of examples. I don't know your linux distro, but when I installed the `bpftrace` package, /usr/share/bpftrace/tools contained a lot of good tracing utilities.

In your case, what you'll need to do (if you're already `root`, remove the `sudo`):

```
cd /usr/share/bpftrace/tools  # or whichever place these tools have been installed to
sudo ./killsnoop
```

Assuming you want to *only* watch signal 15, you will need to modify your script like so:

```c
#!/usr/bin/bpftrace
/*
 * signoop    Trace who issues signal 15 to whom
 * Base on Brendan Gregg's killsnoop, "Trace signals issued by the kill() syscall",

 * USAGE: sigsnoop.bt

 * Copyright 2018 Netflix, Inc.
 * Copyright 2023 Marcus Müller
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License")
 *
 * 07-Sep-2018  Brendan Gregg   Created this.
 * 23-Apr-2023  Marcus Müller made it worse :)
 */

BEGIN
{
    printf("Tracing signal 15... Hit Ctrl-C to end.\n");
    printf("%-9s %-6s %-16s %-4s %-6s %s\n", "TIME", "PID", "COMM", "SIG",
        "TPID", "RESULT");
}

tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_kill
{
    /* here's the relevant part: filter by sig */
  if (args->sig == 15) {
        @tpid[tid] = args->pid;
        @tsig[tid] = args->sig;
    }
}

tracepoint:syscalls:sys_exit_kill
/@tpid[tid]/
{
    time("%H:%M:%S  ");
    printf("%-6d %-16s %-4d %-6d %d\n", pid, comm, @tsig[tid], @tpid[tid],
        args->ret);
    delete(@tpid[tid]);
    delete(@tsig[tid]);
}
```

Save this as `sigsnoop.bt`, give it permissions to be executed by anyone (`chmod 755 sigsnoop.bt`), and run it as root (`sudo ./signsnoop.bt`)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/). You can utilize the [`signal.send`](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/tapsets/API-signal-send.html) probe.

For instance, to monitor for signal 15 sent to a process name `sshd`:

```
$ stap -e 'probe begin { print("Starting monitoring...\n")} 
probe signal.send { 
  if (sig == 15 && pid_name == "sshd") 
    printf ("%s(%d) sent signal 15 to %s(%d)\n", execname(), pid(), pid_name, sig_pid)
}'
```

The output would be something such as:

```
Starting monitoring...
bash(22405) sent signal 15 to sshd(15261)
```

You can even check the command line of the process sending the signal

```
$ stap -e 'probe begin { print("Starting monitoring...\n")}
probe signal.send {
  if (sig == 15 && pid_name == "sshd")
    printf ("%s(%d) (cmdline: \"%s\") sent signal 15 to %s(%d)\n", execname(), pid(),  cmdline_str(), pid_name, sig_pid)
}'

Starting monitoring...
kill(20811) (cmdline: "/usr/bin/kill -15 20809") sent signal 15 to sshd(20809)
```

You can add more info when needed. See which other [tapsets](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/tapsets/) are provided by `systemtap`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your kindly help.

I finally found there is a script that invoked the

```shell
service sshd restart
```

mutliple times repeatedly which caused the problem. By commenting out the statement, the `sshd` no lionger stops now.